# Incomplete Azure download

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I'm having a problem with inclomplete blobs being downloaded from Azure storage. The files that are stored are an images. Almost every file that's downloaded ends up missing several lines on the bottom. I've checked the blobs and they were uploaded correctly.
I'm using the following code for downloading a blob from the Azure service:

```
    private async Task Download(CloudBlobClient client)
    {

            try
            {
                _media = await _directory.CreateFileAsync(ResourceName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var stream = await _media.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var blob = await GetBlob(client);
                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                _category.NotifyAzureProgress();
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }
    }
```

The method GetBlob() looks like this:

```
    private async Task<CloudBlockBlob> GetBlob(CloudBlobClient client)
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(ResourceName);

        return blob;
    }
```

Upload code:

```
    private async Task UploadAsync(CloudBlobClient client)
    {
        _media = await _directory.GetFileAsync(ResourceName);
            using (var stream = await _media.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                var blob = await GetBlob(client);
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
                _category.NotifyAzureProgress();
            }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I've realized I've missed out one detail - the downloaded image has correct dimensions, but several lines from the bottom are black - it doesn't has the same pixels as the source image. I've checked the MD5 hashes and while they match, when I download the image through an external app, they don't match when I download them with the code above.

Edit2: after inspecting the properties of CloudBlob and the output stream, I've noticed, that even though the blob gives correct length after download, the stream usually says something a little lower. I've tried downloading throught range, but to no avail

Comment: Where's the upload code? How are these images getting into the Blob store? It's possible it isn't the download. How did you check the blobs?

Comment: I've checked the blobs through Azure Storage Explorer (http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/). I'll add the upload code.

Comment: You confirmed that the images are intact using a external tool for downloading them? Also, MD5 hash is used for the downloaded content.(I believe it is on by default in the 2.0 SDK)

Comment: Yeah, as I've written above, I've checked those images through the Azure Storage Explorer application. When I try to download those images, they always come out different - sometimes, they are intact, other times a chunk of variable size is missing from the bottom.

Comment: If you try it using the equivalent synchronous methods do you still have the problem? Side note: you shouldn't call `container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()` on every upload - it's a wasted network transaction. Create the container once and then don't call that again if you can help it.

Comment: This is a WinRT app, there are no synchronous equivalents int the library, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip, I'll change the container creation later, but download is a priority now.

Comment: Just to wrap things up - this was offically recognized as a bug by the developers on Github - https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've managed to download the images afterall, by partially using the WinRT Azure library combined with a standard .NET HttpClient.

I used the Azure Lib establish the initial connection and then to get only the Blob reference, because the BlockBlobReference has a method to create Shared Access Signature (and I really didn't want to try to construct it myself). Then I created the HttpClient, made a download URL using the SAS and issued a GET request to the URL, which finally worked and downloaded all the images intact.

I think there might be some weird bug in the official library, since using my download method instead of theirs solved everything.

Code sample:

```
internal async Task Download(CloudBlobClient client)
    {

        try
        {
            _media = await _directory.CreateFileAsync(ResourceName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
                var blob = await GetBlob(client);
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
                policy.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;
                policy.SharedAccessStartTime = new DateTimeOffset(date);
                policy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(date.AddDays(1));
                var signature = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
                var uriString = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri.ToString(), signature);
                var data = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uriString);
                var buf = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)data.Length);
                await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(_media, data);
                _category.NotifyAzureProgress();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _media.DeleteAsync();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```